# Combinatorics proof using the principal of inclusion exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

Suppose that a colony of $n$ ants have $k$ homes. Use the principal of inclusion exclusion to prove the following claim:

Claim: The number of ways the $n$ ants could distribute themselves among the $k$ homes, such that each home has at least one ant, is

$$\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j {k\choose j}(k-j)^n$$

Without the restriction of having at least one ant per home, there would be $k^n$ ways for the ants to pick.

Not sure how I would go about proving this. I tried using the P.I.E., but I am having difficulty finding and excluding any combinations that would result in an empty home. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do the ants count as unique objects, or can we treat them as if they were all the same?

Comment: You can treat them as if they are all unique objects

Comment: If there were in fact all the same, then $k^n$ would be an incorrect amount, as would the intended solution.  You should assume all ants are unique and all homes are unique to get the desired result.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that in my answer.

Comment: As for how to proceed... let $A_i$ represent the event that home $i$ is empty.  We wish to count $|\bigcap A_i^c|$, i.e. the number of ways in which every home is non-empty.  Letting $\Omega$ be the set of arrangements where we don't care, recognize then that $|\bigcap A_i^c| = |\Omega\setminus (\bigcup A_i)| = |\Omega|-|\bigcup A_i|$ and proceed with inclusion-exclusion.  For $j$ of the homes to be intended as empty, pick which $j$ homes those are.  Then for each of the $n$ ants, choose which home they go in (*remembering that $j$ of them are not allowed as a choice*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I am considering all ants and homes to be unique objects.

First choose $k$ of your $n$ ants and put one into each house. There are $_nC_k*k!$ ways to do this, since there are $_nC_k$ ways to choose $k$ ants out of a total $n$, and there are $k!$ ways to put $k$ unique ants into $k$ homes, with one ant in each home.

Now distribute each of the remaining $n-k$ ants into the $k$ homes, no longer having to worry about getting at least one into each home (since one is already in each home). There are, of course, $k^{n-k}$ ways to do this, since we have $k$ possible homes for each of the remaining $n-k$ ants.

This means that the total number of ways is
$$_nC_k*k!*k^{n-k}$$
and so all you have to do now is show that the sum you have written above is equal to this result.

Comment: That's not correct. The formula that Mr/Ms Wick states is; it also equals $k!S(n,k)$ where $S(n,k)$ is a Stirling number of the second kind.

Comment: Why is this incorrect? Is my reasoning wrong, or did I misunderstand whether or not the ants or homes should be counted as unique or the same?

Comment: You are over-counting: your method generates a typical arrangement more than once. In effect you are counting each arrangement many times.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the set of $n$ ants and let $H$ be the set of $k$ homes. Let $\text{Surj}(A,H)$ be the set of surjective maps $f\colon A\to H$ which is a subset of the universe of all mappings $U$ from $A$ to $H$. We want $\lvert \text{Surj}(A,H) \rvert$. To this end, Let 
$$
M_{h_i}=\{f\colon A\to H\quad\text{s.t}\quad f^{-1}(h_i)=\emptyset\}
$$
for $1\leq i \leq k$. Then 
$$
\lvert \text{Surj}(A,H) \rvert=\lvert \bar{M_{h_1}}\cap\dotsb \bar{M_{h_k}}\rvert
$$
which you can compute using the principle of inclusion exclusion formula.